# Como saco los 5 últimos dígitos del número de teléfono

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Para empezar tengo la base de datos 'jardinería'. Muestro el diagrama a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que necesito es modificar los empleados que son representantes de ventas (y que representan a algún cliente) y cuya oficina esté en España para que su extensión telefónica sea los 5 últimos dígitos del teléfono de la oficina.
Pues he conseguido poner este UPDATE junto al SELECT

```
UPDATE empleado, oficina 
SET extension = SUBSTRING(telefono, -5)
WHERE codigo_empleado IN (SELECT DISTINCT e.codigo_empleado
FROM empleado e JOIN cliente c ON e.codigo_empleado = c.codigo_empleado_rep_ventas
JOIN oficina o ON o.codigo_oficina = e.codigo_oficina
WHERE o.pais LIKE 'españa' AND e.puesto LIKE 'Representante ventas');


SELECT DISTINCT e.codigo_empleado, e.extension, o.telefono 
FROM empleado e JOIN cliente c ON e.codigo_empleado = c.codigo_empleado_rep_ventas
JOIN oficina o ON o.codigo_oficina = e.codigo_oficina
WHERE o.pais LIKE 'españa' AND e.puesto LIKE 'Representante ventas';
```

Estoy usando MariaDB. Con el código que he puesto solo he llegado a conseguir los 5 últimos dígitos pero solo del primer número de teléfono que se repite una y otra vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a ver.. tu update, no esta correcto.. como sabe que telefono usar para cada empleado? ahi, falta un join... luego, que sentido tiene poner el cliente en el query, si nunca lo usas?

Comment: @gbianchi Probaré con el join, y sobre el cliente lo uso para saber si es representante de ventas o no. Gracias por el aporte

Comment: no.. el representante de ventas lo sacas de empleado... la tabla c, no la usas en absolutamente ningun lado...